# CSS in PHP echo

Tags: php, css

I am having a problem with the following piece of code:

```
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$answer = "8";
$input = strip_tags($_POST['input']);
if ($submit){ 
    if ($input==$answer){
        echo "Correct";
    }
else
    echo "Wrong";
```

CSS:

```
.wrong {      
margin-top: 5px;       
padding: 5px;    
background-color:#F00;   
border: 2px solid #666;    
width:auto;
color: #000000;   
}
```

All I want is to put a little bit of CSS in with an PHP echo command. If the user gets the answer wrong a red box should appear with "Wrong" in the middle.

I have already tried

```
echo <div class="wrong">"Wrong"</div>;
```

but that did not work.

Comment: [Looks like it works](http://jsfiddle.net/XV4kQ/) to me. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: im trying to get it to display a red box around an echo command, now it is simple to do within html but i need to do it with php     
     
the error i get when i run it is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /hermes/web01b/b2746/moo.roundaboutmkcom/roundaboutmk/coding/index.php on line 25

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP interprets the quote character special, it marks the start or end of a string literal. Either escape your quotes using a backslash or use other single quotes:

```
<style>
.wrong {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #F00;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    width: auto;
    color: #000000;
}
</style>
<?php
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$answer = "8";
$input = strip_tags($_POST['input']);
if ($submit) {
    if ($input == $answer) {
        echo "Correct";
    } else {
        // note: escaped the quote character using a backslash
        echo "<div class=\"wrong\">wrong</div>";
        // alternative:
        //echo '<div class="wrong">wrong</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

See also the [PHP manual on the string type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 3):

please try as:

```
echo '<div class="wrong">Wrong</div>';
```

missing quotes for echo statement.